# Uncountable set of functions without a countable set of generators

Tags: set-theory

Is there a subset $\mathfrak{F}$ of $\omega^\omega$, of cardinality $\aleph_1$, such that no subset $\mathfrak{G}$ of $\mathfrak{F}$ of cardinality $<\aleph_1$ generates $\mathfrak{F}$ in the sense that every function in $\mathfrak{F}$ is a (finite) composition of functions in $\mathfrak{G}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a countable family of functions, then there are only countably many functions which it generates. This is because a function is generated from the family if and only if there is a finite sequence of compositions, and there are only countably many finite sequences from a countable set.

It follows, if so, that no uncountable family of functions is countably generated.

Comment: You are right. My question was trivial. And by the same argument it follows that no uncountable set of function can be spanned by a subset of inferior cardinality. Thanks a lot for taking the trouble to answer!

Comment: No problem, you're most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

That's depends on your definition of $\aleph_1$ and possibly if you accept the continuum hypothesis.

If $\mathfrak G$ is countable then so is the set of finite composition of it's elements. So if $|\mathfrak G|<\aleph_1$ means that $\mathfrak G$ is countable, then no since you don't span a set with enough cardinality.

Comment: $\aleph_1$ is defined as the least cardinal larger than $\aleph_0$, as usual; but I do not see the relevance of CH to my question.

Comment: @Daniel The relevance of CH is if you had defined $\aleph_1$ as the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. My answer depends on that a cardinality less than $\aleph_1$ has to be at most that of a countable set.

Comment: Even if I had defined $\aleph_1$ to be the cardinality of the continuum (a very strange definition, but ok), it would remain true (and by the same argument) that no set of cardinality less than $\mathfrak{c}$ could generate a set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @Daniel Possibly so, but my knowledge at the moment didn't cover that.

Comment: No worries, thanks for answering!